# OPLON LBL ADC When http request location URLs ending in “/”, redirect with same URLs without last “/” with response code 301

Tags: redirect

I want to share with you the solution at this topic, i've solved the problem adding this rule:

```
    <rewriteHeaderRule enable="true" flow="REQUEST" name="redirectRequestCutLastSlash">
            <requestURLMatches>(.*)/$</requestURLMatches>
            <variables>
                <var varName="MY_URI_WITHOUT_LAST_SLASH" from="INNERVAR" name="REQUEST_HTTP_URI_PATH">
                    <regexTag>(.*)/$</regexTag>
                    <replaceTo>$1</replaceTo>
                </var>
            </variables>
            <redirectTo redirectURL="%MY_URI_WITHOUT_LAST_SLASH%" responseCode="301"/>
        </rewriteHeaderRule>
```